# How to create a table with divs and different column width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables, column-width

I have a table created only with divs with fixed width columns. But I need to change width of columns with bootstrap or any other way.

Html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="rTable">
        <div class="rTableHeading">
            <div class="rTableRow">
                <div class="rTableHead">Title1 </div>
                <div class="rTableHead">Title2 </div>
                <div class="rTableHead">Title3 </div>
                <div class="rTableHead">Title4 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableBody">
            <div class="rTableRow">
                <div class="rTableCell">row1</div>
                <div class="rTableCell">row1</div>
                <div class="rTableCell">row1</div>
                <div class="rTableCell">row1</div>                   
            </div>
            <div class="rTableRow">
                <div class="rTableCell">row2</div>
                <div class="rTableCell">row2</div>
                <div class="rTableCell">row2</div>
                <div class="rTableCell">row2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.rTable {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.rTableHeading, .rTableBody, .rTableFoot, .rTableRow {
    clear: both;
}

.rTableHead, .rTableFoot {
    background-color: #FBFBFB;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.rTableCell, .rTableHead {
    padding: 5px !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
    height: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 1.8%;
    width: 24%;
}

.rTableCell {
    height: 46px;
}

.rTable:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

When I need 4 columns I should use `width=24%` for all columns. But how can I create columns with different width? Is there a way to use bootstrap column classes to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your table in correctly first. Then you can resize columns as you want. I have recreated your table in html, and applied the css style to it to change the width of each column.

You should look at nth-child and nth-of-type in W3Schools sometime. Thery're very helpful.

```css
thead th:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
    width: 10%;   
}

thead th:nth-child(2) {
    background: pink;
    width: 20%;   
}

thead th:nth-child(3) {
    background: purple;
    width: 5%;   
}

thead th:nth-child(4) {
    background: green;
    width: 50%;   
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title1</th>
                <th>Title2</th>             
                <th>Title3</th>              
                <th>Title4</th>              
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>row1</td>
                <td>row1</td>
                <td>row1</td>
                <td>row1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>row2</td>
                <td>row2</td>
                <td>row2</td>
                <td>row2</td>                         
            </tr>  
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need a table created by divs, but I used css nth-child as you said for divs.

Comment: ok. glad I could help :-) ...for my experience, pls could you let me know how come you needed a table created by divs?

Comment: Off course, I need to have a form tag on each row. In each row I have some textboxes that their values should post through an ajax call. And it is not possible to have forms on each row of normal tables.

Comment: I see. thank you :-) this maybe useful for me in future :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, try this. If I understand the question correctly that is. I'm not 100% sure where you want to actually add the width, but I would assume this would do what you are asking for.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="rTable">
        <div class="rTableHeading">
            <div class="rTableRow">
                <div class="rTableHead col-sm-3">Title1 </div>
                <div class="rTableHead col-sm-3">Title2 </div>
                <div class="rTableHead col-sm-3">Title3 </div>
                <div class="rTableHead col-sm-3">Title4 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableBody">
            <div class="rTableRow">
                <div class="rTableCell col-sm-3">row1</div>
                <div class="rTableCell col-sm-3">row1</div>
                <div class="rTableCell col-sm-3">row1</div>
                <div class="rTableCell col-sm-3">row1</div>                   
            </div>
            <div class="rTableRow">
                <div class="rTableCell col-sm-3">row2</div>
                <div class="rTableCell col-sm-3">row2</div>
                <div class="rTableCell col-sm-3">row2</div>
                <div class="rTableCell col-sm-3">row2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also, I would take out the width% in your CSS for rTableCell if you are utilizing the bootstrap column sizing. You can still add sizing here if you would like to see how it impacts your columns. It isn't right or wrong, but first see what it looks like without the width% and then come back to add width to your liking.

```
.rTableCell, .rTableHead {
    padding: 5px !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
    height: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 1.8%;
    /* width: 24%; */ 
}
```

Comment: This solution makes each column as a row. Strange behavior!

Comment: It shouldn't, we are only applying column properties to each div underneath the row. Could you attach a screenshot of a before and after so we can get a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry I changed the code. It was like each rTableHead and rTableCell in one row with 100% width. I think it is because of the styles that override bootstrap col-* classes.

Comment: No worries! Glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better solution with bootstrap but I used this approach for now.

```
.rTableHeading .rTableHead:nth-child(1) ,
.rTableBody .rTableCell:nth-child(1) {
    width: 30%;   
}

.rTableHeading .rTableHead:nth-child(2) ,
.rTableBody .rTableCell:nth-child(2) { 
    width: 30%;   
}

.rTableHeading .rTableHead:nth-child(3) ,
.rTableBody .rTableCell:nth-child(3) {  
    width: 15%;   
}

.rTableHeading .rTableHead:nth-child(4) ,
.rTableBody .rTableCell:nth-child(4) {  
    width: 20%;   
}
```

I also cleared `width=24%` from `rTableCell` and  `rTableHead`.